# Using file explorer connected to SharePoint online under the OneDrive building icon listed as System

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can't add to row for a second level folder with third level folders under it. It shows as read-only and admin level is no help.

Comment: It is apparently only the folder row that will not accept a picture in a picture column.

Comment: This is from Windows 10 fully updated,

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean “add to row”? Are you having trouble update SharePoint document library from synced folder in OneDrive?

Comment: Thank you Josh McClanahan and Chelsea_MSFT for trying to work with my poorly asked question.

Comment: I can make a picture column and hid the first normal column so a picture appears first in all the rows except the first row. But I want it to be the first thing in the top left corner of the view. In fact I would like the picture to show in the next level up also.